# Custom columnsep in twocolumn book

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, book-design

I'm trying to customize the column separator for my two columns book class. I made a simple `Tikz` line to put between them but I find no way to do so. Here's a MWE of my code (I'm compiling it with `LuaLaTeX` for I desire to use some other features later):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twocolumn,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
        paper = a5paper,
        layout = a5paper,
        layoutsize = {148 mm, 210 mm},
        includehead = true,
        includefoot = true,
        inner = 1.5 cm,
        outer = 1 cm,
        top = 1.5 cm,
        bottom = 1.5 cm,
        columnsep = .6cm,
        twoside = true,
        twocolumn = true,
        showframe = false,
    }
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

The `Tikz` separator is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width = 2pt] (0,0) to (0,-10);
    \fill (0,-10.5) circle (.1);
    \draw[red] (0,-10.5) circle (.3);
    \fill[green, opacity=.3] (0,-10.5) circle (.4);
    \draw[line width = 2pt] (0,-11) to (0,-21);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

On the left you can see what I have, and on the right what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Columnseps]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can patch `\@outputdblcol` and replace the `\normalcolor\vrule\@width\columnseprule` with your Ti*k*Z code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twocolumn,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
        paper = a5paper,
        layout = a5paper,
        layoutsize = {148 mm, 210 mm},
        includehead = true,
        includefoot = true,
        inner = 1.5 cm,
        outer = 1 cm,
        top = 1.5 cm,
        bottom = 1.5 cm,
        columnsep = .6cm,
        twoside = true,
        twocolumn = true,
        showframe = false,
    }
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\show\@outputdblcol
\patchcmd\@outputdblcol
  {\normalcolor\vrule\@width\columnseprule}
  {\mydrawcolumnseprule}
  {}{\GenericError{}{Patching \string\@outputdblcol\space failed}{}{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\mydrawcolumnseprule
  {%
    % giving the lengths in multiples of `\textheight` seems like a good idea
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[line width = 2pt] (0,0) to (0,-.48\textheight);
      \fill (0,-.5\textheight) circle (.005\textheight);
      \draw[red] (0,-.5\textheight) circle (.01\textheight);
      \fill[green, opacity=.3] (0,-.5\textheight) circle (.015\textheight);
      \draw[line width = 2pt] (0,-.52\textheight) to (0,-\textheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** The following tells TeX that the `tikzpicture` has zero size, it will be aligned somewhere at the bottom of the textblock, so you have to draw in positive vertical direction to get the same results.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twocolumn,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
        paper = a5paper,
        layout = a5paper,
        layoutsize = {148 mm, 210 mm},
        includehead = true,
        includefoot = true,
        inner = 1.5 cm,
        outer = 1 cm,
        top = 1.5 cm,
        bottom = 1.5 cm,
        columnsep = .6cm,
        twoside = true,
        twocolumn = true,
        showframe = false,
    }
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@outputdblcol
  {\normalcolor\vrule\@width\columnseprule}
  {\mydrawcolumnseprule}
  {}{\GenericError{}{Patching \string\@outputdblcol\space failed}{}{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\mydrawcolumnseprule
  {%
    % giving the lengths in multiples of `\textheight` seems like a good idea
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox ; % now the tikzpicture doesn't take up any space
      \draw[line width = 2pt] (0,-.01\textheight) to (0,.48\textheight);
      \fill (0,.5\textheight) circle (.005\textheight);
      \draw[red] (0,.5\textheight) circle (.01\textheight);
      \fill[green, opacity=.3] (0,.5\textheight) circle (.015\textheight);
      \draw[line width = 2pt] (0,.52\textheight) to (0,\textheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked really well. But in the case if the rule made in `tikz` does not cover all the text height it gets stuck at the bottom and I can't center it at the middle of the text height.

Comment: @Levy you can trick TeX into thinking the height was different...

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Levy see my edit.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much!!