# Put each text on each column

Tags: luatex, two-column, book-design

How can I put texts from different languages in each column on a two column book class? I tried the `paracol` package but it doesn't look good for my entire file. I put here a MWE of my code (compiled with `LuaLaTeX`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,twocolumn,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
        inner = 1.5 cm,
        outer = 1 cm,
        top = 1.5 cm,
        bottom = 1.5 cm,
        columnsep = .8cm,
    }
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \disablehyphenation

\begin{document}

    \chapter*{Each lang on each column}

    1. Text in english in which I wish it could be translated on the other side. \\
    2. Other example.

    \vspace{13cm}

    1. Texte en français dans lequel je souhaite qu'il puisse être traduit de l'autre côté. \\
    2. Autre exemple.

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to do so?

[image]

Comment: What was the problem with paracol?  Seriously, it does this sort of thing all the time.

Comment: I have made a custom `columnsep` as seen here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498552/choose-columnsep-depending-on-page and the `paracol` package messes really bad with it.

Comment: Ah, you modified `\@outputdblcol` which isn't used by paracol (or multicol).

Comment: I would suggest using everypage and tikzpagenodes, assuming you only have two sizes of divider (chapter and full page).